Send a request WebSocket for OBS
i would like try change scene on my obs, but when i execute the code the obs, hasn't change the scene. I would like understand why?? At the moment i have "Scene" abd "Scene2"
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri("ws://192.168.1.68:4455");

    using (ClientWebSocket webSocket = new ClientWebSocket())
    {
        try
        {
            await webSocket.ConnectAsync(uri, CancellationToken.None);

            Console.WriteLine("Conexão estabelecida com o servidor OBS WebSocket.");

            //await SendMessage(webSocket, "{\"request-type\":\"GetVersion\",\"message-id\":\"1\"}");

            await SendMessage(webSocket, "{\"requestType\":\"SetCurrentSceneCollection\",\"requestData\": {\"sceneCollectionName\": \"Scene\"}}");
            //await SendMessage(webSocket, "{\"request-type\":\"GetCurrentScene\",\"message-id\":\"1\"}");
            string response = await ReceiveMessage(webSocket);


            //string response = await ReceiveMessage(webSocket);
            Console.WriteLine($"Resposta do servidor: {response}");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Erro ao conectar ao servidor OBS WebSocket: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}

static async Task SendMessage(ClientWebSocket webSocket, string message)
{
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
    await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
}

static async Task<string> ReceiveMessage(ClientWebSocket webSocket)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    var result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, result.Count);
}

I use websocket and my version of obs is 30.1.1. I'm readed the documentation from [github](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-websocket/blob/master/docs/generated/protocol.md#setcurrentscenecollection)

This doesn't follow the message format.

It may be your JSON request, it might be missing required fields leading to OBS ignoring your request. To validate you have everything you need in your request, you can use the following website which will show you the JSON used for each request.
https://obs-raw.streamer.bot/
However, I would suggest using the obs-websocket-dotnet library as it makes connecting to the OBS websocket much easier and handles a lot of the message requirement to listen for events such as scene changes or trigger them yourself. You can find the installation instructions here.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/obs-websocket-dotnet
After you import the libraries, you can connect to the websocket like this
private void connectToOBS()
{
    OBSWebsocket client = new OBSWebsocket();
    client.ConnectAsync("ws://" + ip + ":" + port, password);
}

You can subscribe to events such as scene changes using code such as
private void connectToOBS()
{
    client = new OBSWebSocket()
    client.CurrentProgramSceneChanged += onSceneChanged;
    client.ConnectAsync("ws://" + ip + ":" + port, password);
}

private void onSceneChanged(object sender, ProgramSceneChangedEventArgs e) 
{
    // Do Work
}

To change scene, you can call on the client:
private void oBSChangeScene()
{
    client.SetCurrentProgramScene(sceneName)
}

You can do it without the use of a library by managing the connection and the messaging yourself, but the use of the library will simplify the task for you. I would also recommend you implement onConnect and onDisconnect functions which are implemented the same way as the CurrentProgramSceneChanged. This will let you check that you are connected to OBS and reconnect automatically should you become disconnected for any reason.
